# FX portfolio MV estimation for undelying Spot move

Tags: option-pricing, greeks, exotics, estimation, interpolation

In the context of a project involving FX derivatives, I am faced with the challenge of estimating the change in the market value of my portfolio in response to a change in the underlying spot.

The conventional approach involves a full reevaluation of the portfolio, but due to computational constraints, especially with large portfolios containing exotic products that require partial differential equation (PDE) solving for pricing, this method may not be viable.

To address this issue, I initially explored using Taylor approximation with delta and gamma for a small spot bump, which provides a reasonable estimation. However, for larger bumps, the accuracy of the approximation diminishes, particularly when the portfolio involves complex products with sharp gamma moves.

In light of these considerations, I am now contemplating forming a grid, e.g. FX Spot going up and down 0.1%, 1%, 3% and use an interpolation method to estimate the points in between.

My question to the community is: What interpolation model would be most suitable for my grid of points, and why? I am seeking insights into the choice of interpolation models that strike a balance between accuracy in the MV estimation as well as replicating the dynamics of my portfolio.(I am not sure that a simple cubic spline may be enough for this)

PS : I am making for now the assumtion that my target MV is an infinetely differentiable function with no jumps in the delta and gamma (far from barriers of my exotics)